# Return polygon locations for the districts of a city

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

This query returns district boundaries and admin_center-s too, I wonder if there is a way to exclude admin_center-s using the api.
https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/RWJ

Comment: Not sure how to interpret your question. Your query just returns relations. These relations contain references to other elements, such as nodes with the role `admin_centre`. However, these nodes are not returned by the query. It just returns a reference to them because this reference is part of the relation.

Comment: I see, I'm basically looking for a way to exclude the reference nodes with the role admin_centre, not sure if that's possible

Comment: Probably not at server-side. Just strip them off yourself at client-side.